# WysiwygPro editor shows session expired error

Tags: php, html

WysiwygPro editor shows "Your editing session has expired. This is usually caused by a long period of inactivity. Please re-load the page." error dialog when any of the controls is clicked like Image, Media, Emoticon etc.
This is only reproducible on CENTOS 8 - working fine on CENTOS 6 and 7.

Comment: Check your [session lif time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) in `php.ini` configurations

Comment: Already checked, it is set to 1440.

Comment: Then session will lost after 1440 s / 60 = 24 minutes

Comment: Yes, but it shows session expired error on click of any of editor controls like image upload.

Comment: You seem to be using something rather old (defunct even), you should consider other options. In any case, have you tried a google search for your specific problem (that yield potential solutions like this [one](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/file-manager-html-editor-session-expired-problem.138661/#post607185))?

Comment: Thank you nitrin0, yes I did saw the link you shared and already checked for session.save_path - it is same for both the machines with centos 7 and 8. On centos 7 machine everything is working where as on centos 8 I am getting this session expired error.

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be the session file that can't be written.
Try the following:

- Temorarily disable SELinux with `setenforce 0`

If this fixes the problem, then search for the denied resource with `audit2why < /var/log/audit.log`
If so, you can change the context of your session path to allow httpd:

Non permanent solution:

```
chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0 /path/to/your/session/storage
```

Permanent solution:

```
semanage fcontext --add -t httpd_var_run_t /path/to/your/session/storage(.*)?"
restorecon -r /path/to/your/session/storage
```

Once you're done, re-enable SELinux with `setenforce 1`

- Unable to write session files because of permissions

Identify where your session files are written, eg `session.save_path = "/tmp"` in php.ini if you're using mod_php, or someting like `php_value[session.save_path] = /var/www/$pool/sessions` if your using php-fpm.

Check if those directories are owned by `httpd` with at least `750` rights.

If all of the above don't succeed, you should try reading your php error logs and httpd error logs and post evidence.